# Arrendodar números financeiramente

Tags: vb.net, arredondamento

Estou montando um sistema de folha de pagamento básico no VB.NET, e por exemplo, quando eu faço divisão de `2500` por `220` o resultado será `11,363636363636363636363636363636`.

Tem como eu fazer um arredondamento por exemplo para resultado ficar `11,36` duas casas após a vírgula

Comment: `decimal value = Math.Round(2500M / 220, 2);`

Comment: certo, mas onde eu devo coloca-lo? no textbox em que exibe o resultado?

Comment: Então ai já é uma decisão sua, aonde tu vai exibir !?

Comment: Então é que eu coloquei no textbox, mas fica com erro, coloquei exatamente o mesmo codigo que voce me passou, mas aparece a mensagem " 'Decimal' is a type and cannot be used as an expression." dizendo que 'decimal' é um tipo e nao pode ser usado como uma expressao. Desculpa é que eu ainda nao entendo muito.

Comment: Matheus coloca o código que você está fazendo na pergunta

Comment: Dim num7 As Double                                                                              Dim num8 As Double
num7 = Val(TextBox7.Text) num8 = Val(TextBox8.Text)
  TextBox10.Text = num7 / num8                 seria esse aqui

Comment: acredito que seja `TextBox10.Text = Math.Round(num7/num8,2).ToString();` se baseando pelo comentário.

Comment: isso ai mesmo, deu certo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @MateusJustino A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o [`Round()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_System_Int32_). Espero que esteja usando o [`decimal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimalWT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) na folha de pagamento.

Tem casos que precisa lidar com a sobra do arredondamento por força de legislação.

```
Imports System.Console
Imports System.Math

Public Class Program
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        WriteLine(Round(2500D / 220, 2))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Veja [funcionando **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JUCR5i). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D0KfwM). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Round.vb).

Comment: A sim compreendo, mas você poderia me ensinar a usar a função Round() ou me passar um tutorial na internet que a ensine, nunca usei ela.

Comment: @MateusJustino `System.Math.Round(dec numeroDeEntrada, int decimais)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx