# Por que o "If" não consegue verificar igualdade entre CType(double, int32) com int32?

Tags: vb.net, if

Eu tenho uma função que me retorna um `Double` e preciso verificar se o resultado é igual a 5000. Eu estou usando `If CType(resultadoFunção as double, Int32) = 5000 Then`, mas embora ele mostre 5000, ele não retorna `True`. Por que?

```
 Private Async Sub Teste1()
    'Necessário Engucv
    'Imports Emgu.CV

    'vid = caminho de algum video
    Capiture = New VideoCapture(vid)

    While True
        Dim m As New Mat
        Capiture.Read(m)
        PictureBox1.Image = m.Bitmap
        Label1.Text = CType(Capiture.GetCaptureProperty(CvEnum.CapProp.PosMsec), Int32).ToString
        Await Task.Delay(42)

        If CType(Capiture.GetCaptureProperty(CvEnum.CapProp.PosMsec), Int32) = 5000 Then
            'Faz algo
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto ocorre porque o tipo `Double` não tem exatidão e para ser igual precisa ser **exatamente** igual, uma diferença mínima não é aceitável, já é diferente. Você pode ver mais detalhes em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). No momento que faz essa conversão provavelmente está gerando um número como 4999.99999999999998 e aí a parte inteira é 4999, portanto diferente de 5000. [O uso de um `Round()` pode resolver o problema neste caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255701/101), mas cuidado com outros.